# What is the difference between cointegration and the VECM?

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

What is the difference between cointegration and the vector error correction model (VECM)? I applied cointegration test and found long run association between variables, so should I apply VECM?

Comment: Yes, you can apply the VECM once you have found cointegration.

Comment: Strictly speaking the VECM is just a VAR written in a different way. But if you have cointegration, it implies reduced rank on one of the coefficient matrices.

Answer (score 1):

*Cointegration* is a *phenomenon* that may be exhibited by a group of integrated time series; *being cointegrated* is a *feature* that may be posessed by a group of integrated time series. Let us consider a simple example. If series $x_{1,t},\dotsc,x_{m,t}$ are individually I(1) (integrated of order 1) and there exists a linear combination $y_t=\beta_1 x_{1,t}+\dotsc+\beta_m x_{m,t}$ that is I(0) (stationary), then we face the phenomenon of cointegration, and the group of series $x_{1,t},\dotsc,x_{m,t}$ posess the feature of being cointegrated. If no linear combination is I(0), then there is no cointegration and the series taken together are not cointegrated.

*Vector error correction model (VECM)* is a *model* that can be used for modelling cointegrated time series. A very simple example is a bivariate VECM with no lags for two integrated-and-cointegrated time series $x_{1,t}$ and $x_{2,t}$,

$$ \Delta x_{1,t} = \alpha_1 (x_{1,t-1}-\beta x_{2,t-1}) + \varepsilon_{1,t}, $$
$$ \Delta x_{2,t} = \alpha_2 (x_{1,t-1}-\beta x_{2,t-1}) + \varepsilon_{2,t}. $$

It shows that the series $x_{1,t}$ reacts to the most recent (as of time $t-1$) disequilibrium between itself and the other series and "corrects" (given a suitable value of $\alpha_1$) to reduce the disequilibrium (moves towards equilibrium). The same could be said about $x_{2,t}$.